# predict next purchase time of an item

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, statistics, forecasting, time

I have a bunch of timestamps (purchase date from history), that looks like:

> [1658753101, 1658760061, 1658824861, 1658846461, 1658853961, etc]

What I want is to based on that list predict next item sale time.
Also I think the closer we are to the present, the more valuable the data is.
I've tried to get the average difference and predict from it, but the result is disappointing

Comment: Have you tried to visualize it and find some patterns?